# Regex find words that have at least X characters with no more than Y sequential repetitions of a character

Tags: regex

I have a whole lot of OCR'ed text that has quite a lot of unwanted text in it.
The problem at hand is to find words with at least 3 characters in them but does NOT have more than 3 sequential repetitions of the same character.

I have gotten as far as getting two differnt Regex expressions works for the two different rules but not sure how to combine them

This one matches words with 3 sequential repetitions: (This will need to be negated when combined with the next one)
(.*)\1{2,}

This one matches words with 3 or more alpha characters
\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}\b

I now need to add these two together and make one expression.
Here are some examples

Words I want to match

- Jack
- Slack
- Traack
- Maacka

Words I DO NOT want to match

- Jac (Not long enough)
- Slaaack (Has 3 SEQUENTIAL repetitions of "A")

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How is `Jac` not long enough, it has 3 characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for the detection of repeating characters. You know the rest of the solution already :-)

```
/\b(?![a-z]*?([a-z])\1{2})[a-z]{3,}\b/i
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response, Here is the expression I ended up with.
(\b(?![a-z]*([a-z])\2{2}))[a-z]{4,}\b